# Using Windows Server 2012 like a regular operating system

Tags: cpu, windows-server-2012

I am in the process of designing a custom computer for work. I've been leaning towards building a system with 4 physical processors in it, However no windows versions except for the server releases support more than 2 physical processors.

Say I built a rig with 4x Hex-core Intel Xeons, 512 GB of RAM, and installed Windows Server 2012 onto the system. Could I use it as I would regular Windows 8? I would not be using this system as a server, but rather a Graphics and Video Editing workstation- I would be running software such as Cinema4D, Photoshop, Davinci Resolve, Premiere, VRay, etc. Would such software be able to operate properly on a server OS with this many physical processors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing the specifics, my answer would be **yes**, Server 2012 is basically Windows 8 with the bells and whistles still attached and not dressed up in drag, there is nothing stopping you using it as a regular workstation.

Bare in mind that some programs might have no idea what to do with all those cores though (they may only use 4/8 etc.), some programs also behave weirdly on a computer with over 20 logical cores (IE. Don't install/don't run), so research what you're going to use it for first.

Any program that is compatible with Windows 8 **should** install on Server 2012 without issue.

Comment: Thanks! I'm doing research on what applications i will be using and if they will work with server but so far most all of them seem to be compatible.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @YetiFiasco and would add that you may want to confirm any program you'll be using that you would consider 'critical' is actually *supported* by the software vendor on Server 2012.  If you encounter a problem and need support, you don't want to be told "no support for you!" simply because you're not running a supported OS.  You can try arguing that the underlying OS is the same, but if what you're doing is mission critical, you don't really want to find out your on your own *after* a problem brings your program to its knees.

Comment: In my experience Twisty's comment is something to be concerned about. This especially applies to "system utilities" like anti-malware, backup, and similar functions. The vendors say "oh, Server edition? You must buy our 'enterprise-level' product! Ka-ching!" There's no reason why such stuff shouldn't work on Server - but it actively checks, and refuses to.